# Xcodebuild test hangs indefinitely without error

Tags: ios, unit-testing, jenkins, xcode7, xcodebuild

Xcodebuild hangs indefinitely in Jenkins. But same setup works properly in local machine.

(Xcode 7.3.1, OS X 10.11.6)

Command executed (After clearing DerivedData & Clean)

xcodebuild  -scheme APP_SCHEME -derivedDataPath ./DerivedData -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'OS=9.3,name=iPhone 6' ARCHS=x86_64  VALID_ARCHS=x86_64  ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=YES test

Launches app in simulator and then Hangs indefinitely after following command without any error

touch APPSCHEME.xctest

Comment: clear the derived data and try once

Comment: Cleared DerivedData... Then executed the clean command even then it got stuck in  the same position

Answer (score 0):

xcodebuild hangs because it is not able to find & launch the appropriate simulator.
Verify whether the below 2 commands gives the matching list of simulators and they are in available state.
 - xcrun simctl list 
 - instruments -s devices

If not, then proceed on to do a clean uninstall of Xcode,install and then try running the command again

1. Delete Xcode from Applications folder
2. In  ~/Library/Developer/ Delete Xcode and CoreSimulator folder
3. sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
4. sudo rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
5. sudo rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode/
6. Clean Trash
7. Restart Install Xcode ,Launch and Accept license Agreement and then Restart